# php templating header and footer

Tags: php, html, php-include

For each page on the site I have a header and footer, so I decided to create a template for both then just include them on each page.

```
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
   contents of the page...        
<?php include_once("footer.php")?>
```

`header.php` contains:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Items Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/item.css">
<script src="assets/css/item.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        contains a navigation bar  
    </header>
```

`footer.php` contains:

```
    <footer>...</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

The above codes are for the Items page however I also have Users page they both have the same footer and header markup however different linked CSS and JS files. How can change `<link>` and `<script>` inside the `<head>` tag on the `header.php` include file if the user navigates to the user page, for example: `mysite.com/user/blabla`.

The correct link for the Users page should be:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/user.css">
<script src="assets/css/user.js"></script>
```

Comment: u have login page for user , or simply static page

Comment: yes I have a login, is that necessary to know?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this format in all pages

```
<?php    
    $page_title = "title_here";
    $cssfiles   = array("path/to/css1.css", "path/to/css2.css", ...);
    $jsfiles    = array("path/to/js1.js", "path/to/js2.js", ...);    
?>
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
   contents of the page...        
<?php include_once("footer.php")?>
```

And in **header.php**

```
<head>
    <title><?php echo $page_title;?></title>
    <?php
    foreach($cssfiles as $css){
    ?>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $css;?>">
    <?php
    }
    foreach($jsfiles as $js){
    ?>
        <script src="<?php echo $js;?>"></script>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

User Type Page

```
<?php
$pageType = 2; // USER
?>
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
   contents of the page...        
<?php include_once("footer.php")?>
```

in other pages

```
<?php
$pageType = 1; // OTHER
?>
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
   contents of the page...        
<?php include_once("footer.php")?>
```

and in header

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>

<?php if ( $pageType == 1 ) { ?>
    <title>Items Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/item.css">
    <script src="assets/css/item.js"></script>
<?php } else if ( $pageType == 2 ) { ?>
    <title>User Page</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/user.css">
    <script src="assets/css/user.js"></script>
<?php } ?>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Split up your nav and header include.

header.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Items Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/item.css">
<script src="assets/css/item.js"></script>
```

nav.php

```
</head>
<body>
<header>
    contains a navigation bar  
</header>
```

whatever.php

```
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/user.css">
<script src="assets/css/user.js"></script>
<?php include_once("nav.php")?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
session_start();
if($_SESSION['user'])
{
?>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/item_user.css">
    <script src="assets/css/item_user.js"></script>
<?php
}
else
{
?>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/item.css">
    <script src="assets/css/item.js"></script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to set every page a variable for css and javascript like so:

```
 $css        = 'assets/css/user.css';
 $javascript = 'assets/css/user.js';
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
   contents of the page...        
<?php include_once("footer.php")?>
```

on the header page you need to call those variable:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Items Page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo $css; ?>">
<script src="<?php echo $javascript; ?>"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        contains a navigation bar  
    </header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

header.php

```
if(!isset($custom_css)) {
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/item.css">';
}

if(!isset($custom_js)) {
    echo '<script src="assets/css/item.js"></script>';
}
```

And in your users files, give values to `$custom_css` and `$custom_js` before including header
user.php

```
$custom_css = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/user.css">';
$custom_js = '<script src="assets/css/item.js"></script>';
<?php include_once("header.php")?>
```